# Word Choice - Surmise

Tags: word-choice, grammar

*"Even the smallest surmise of her husband dying scared her to death"*

Is the word surmise used correctly in this sentence? Maybe *"assumption"* would fit better?

Comment: I wouldn't use either of your suggestions. But ***suggestion*** (or perhaps ***hint***) would work fine. It won't resolve the "quirkiness" of the juxtaposition between the husband literally dying and the wife being figuratively scared to death, though.

Comment: How can one say this without the abrupt shift you mentioned?

Comment: If you like the quirkiness or don't think it matters, you don't need to do anything. Otherwise just use some other figurative expression such as *...put the fear of God into her*, or be more literal *(...terrified her).*

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not going to bother trying to establish it from a corpus search, but I more than suspect that [*even the **slightest hint***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22even+the+slightest+hint%22) would win the popularity contest hands down. It's almost a "set phrase".

Comment: I think u answered the question FumbleFingers and the question can be closed

Comment: I was thinking someone might fill me in on whether your use of *surmise* is "acceptable" or not (although I wouldn't use it *myself* in that context, I wasn't sure if that was just a personal stylistic preference). But I've just been to the trouble of checking it out in the full OED, where the relevant definition is *†b. A ‘**suspicion**’, slight trace (of something)*. I then went to even *more* trouble to establish that **†** is a symbol they sometimes use as an alternative to **Obs** (olete), for reasons that aren't clear to me. In "not-so-short", *you* shouldn't use it like that either.

Comment: ...in light of which, since I learned something myself from this question, I certainly don't want to be the one calling for it to be closed. It's still potentially useful to others and could benefit from a proper "Answer", even if you've got what *you* wanted out of it.

Answer (score 2):

To surmise involves making an educated guess.

> After listening to the world renown evolutionary biologist's lecture, I surmised that no form of theism was part of his perspective or repertoire.

The auditor in this sentence, based on hearing perhaps just one lecture by the biologist, makes an educated guess that the biologist ascribes no legitimacy to the belief in a supernatural being called god (or God). Is his surmise accurate? Possibly. Only by questioning the lecturer in this regard could the surmise give way to a confirmed conclusion.

I therefore surmise that the word *surmise* is not a good fit for your sentence. A more appropriate word would be *inkling*, which [means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inkling) essentially

> - A slight hint or indication.
> - A slight understanding or vague idea or notion.

Moreover, the word *smallest* should probably give way to the word *slightest*. The consequent sentence would therefore be:

> "Even the slightest inkling of her husband dying scared her to death"

Or,

> "Even the slightest inkling of her husband's death virtually scared *her* to death."

Notice I italicized the second appearance of the word *her* in order to soften, as it were, the second appearance of the word *death*. The word *virtually* also
reinforces the idea that her fear was serious but hardly fatal!